# android app with kafka consumer integration issue

Tags: android, apache-kafka

I am writing a simple android app in java in which I am trying to connect to kafka broker.

I have added below dependency in my gradle file.

implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.5.0'

After that, if I run my app, it throws below error

[image: snappy-java and kafka-client both throw error]

snappy-java errors

1.
MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26): Lorg/xerial/snappy/pool/DirectByteBuffers$2;run()Ljava/lang/Void;

2.
MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26): Lorg/xerial/snappy/SnappyFramed;lambda$static$0(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;)Ljava/util/zip/Checksum;

kafka-client jar error

1.

[image]

2.

Error: UnsupportedFeature(invoke-polymorphic-method-handle)

Appreciate any help here.

Thanks